# JSF page gets old data after refreshing the page using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf

How can I get the new data after refreshing the page. I updated the data (from ) using hibernate and this is working fine. When I logout and then login then I am getting the new data. But when I just do the page refresh it is showing old data. Any solution for this?

My pagemodel is @Viewscoped. Calling saveUser method from pagemodel. saveUser method is in Handler. Code are following:

public void saveUser(Long usrId, String firstName, String lastName, String loginName, String password, String emailAddr, Company companyId, PhoneNumber businessPhoneNUmber) {

```
AllCompanyDAO aDAO = new AllCompanyDAO(session);

 User user = new User();    


 Long changedBy = (long) 0;
 Long createdBy = (long) 0;

 Date date = new Date();


 user.setUsrId(usrId) ;
 user.setFirstName(firstName);
  user.setLastName(lastName);
  user.setLoginName(loginName);
  user.setPassword(password);
  user.setEmailAddr(emailAddr);
  user.setChangedBy(changedBy);
  user.setCreatedBy(createdBy);
  user.setCreatedDate(date);
  user.setChangedDate(date);
  user.setCompany(companyId);
  user.setBusinessPhoneNumber(businessPhoneNUmber);

    aDAO.saveOrUpdate(businessPhoneNUmber);

session.flush();
    session.evict(businessPhoneNUmber);
```

}

Solution:::: I got the solution. :-) I used @RequestScoped instead of @ViewScoped and it gets the latest data from DB after refreshing the page.

Comment: Have you tested this in different browsers? Looks more like a browser caching old requests.

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and firefox. Both showing same. Any alternatives.

Comment: Then looks like you're not retrieving the results when loading your page. Make sure you use a `@ViewScoped` managed bean and not a `@SessionScoped` one. Otherwise, please post your code in order to get help.

Comment: sent an email of my code. Thanks.

Comment: That's not how the site works. You have to edit your question and add the code there. If you have problems formatting the code, just leave it there until somebody edit it for you. Cleaning my email...

Comment: new link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467620/jsf-page-old-data-after-refresing-the-page-using-hibernate

Comment: What part of **edit your question** didn't you understand? Please edit **this** question, add your code **at the bottom** and delete the duplicate question.

Comment: Is there anyone who can tell me the problem?

Comment: From your code above, you save the data but never recover the new list of data.

Comment: How can I recover new data?

Comment: The same way you recover when initializing the bean?

Comment: Ok, how you recover the data to show it to the user when your page starts?

Comment: My saveUser method update the data in the database. what do I have to write to recover the data?

Comment: You must have a method where you recover (load) your data in a `List<Something>` and then show it in your page maybe using `<h:dataTable>`.

Comment: <h:inputText id="areaCode" label="Area Code" required="true" maxlength="50" 
                     value="#{UserAdminPageModel.user.businessPhoneNumber.areaCode}" />
        <h:message for="areaCode"></h:message> 

I used the above code to show the data from the database.

Comment: Looks like you're just learning about generic application development. It would be better if you grab a JSF tutorial and follow it step by step instead of trying something out of nowhere. There are good resources on the net and in [StackOverflow JSF wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: I displayed the data in textbox and all the textboxes are in a richpanel. Then I used 
<h:commandButton value="#{labelBundle.saveLabel}"         action="#{UserAdminPageModel.saveUser}" render="userPanel" />
to call the Bean method.